# Book in which humanity is extinct and AI's wage war against each other

Tags: story-identification, books, robots, artificial-intelligence

The only other detail my friend could remember is that the AI's that looked the most human were considered superior to those who were not humanoid, i.e. a spider mech that performs hull maintenance.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to SciFi Stack Exchange! Be sure to check out the Help Section (https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help) in order to understand how to ask questions!

Comment: It's been a while since I read them, but could this be a garbled recollection of *Saturn's Children* and *Neptune's Brood* by Charles Stross?